# How decide which pin right for interrupts?

Tags: sensor, stm32, interrupts, imu, gyro

I would like to ask about I2C sensor's interrupt pins connection to STM32F. I use ADXL345 Ggyro sensor. I would like to connect sensor to STM32F446RE (64 LQFP). But I do not know what I need to know about it? How can decide which STM pins right for INT1 and INT2?

Also I use I2C3 port for ADXL. I do not know only one point how to connect INT1 and INT2 pin?

Datasheet of STM32F446:
https://static6.arrow.com/aropdfconversion/ff3e5f6c95ecaedac15f282df78dd9579fbd73ca/201916482129812dm00141306.pdf

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMQr4.png)

Comment: Well you should ask yourself why you want to connect them and what do you think can be achieved by connecting them. Just as a counter example, even if a chip has a pin that is named as interrupt output pin, it does not mean it must be used for generating interrupts on the MCU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The external interrupt/event controller consists of 23 edge-detector
> lines used to generate interrupt/event requests. Each line can be
> independently configured to select the trigger event (rising edge,
> falling edge, both) and can be masked independently. A pending
> register maintains the status of the interrupt requests. The EXTI can
> detect an external line with a pulse width shorter than the Internal
> APB2 clock period. Up to 114 GPIOs can be connected to the 16 external
> interrupt lines.

Source: https://static6.arrow.com/aropdfconversion/ff3e5f6c95ecaedac15f282df78dd9579fbd73ca/201916482129812dm00141306.pdf

Then use the [cube mx tool](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubemx.html) to help you configure the pin and generate code for the HAL.